# c++ type erasure / type encapsulation? discover type

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure

I am probably totally off base on this, but I'm coming from c# so I apologize in advance.

First, a little bit about what I'm trying to do.  I have a factory base class defined in my code as

```
template<typename _Ty>
class Factory
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<_Ty> Create() = 0;
};
```

What I want to do then is have a list of factories (say a stl vector or list) and be able to then search for them by the template type.  So far I've figured out I need a vector or list of a containing type of some sort so I came up with:

```
class FactoryContainer
{
    struct FactoryConcept {
        virtual ~FactoryConcept() {}
    };

    template< typename _Ty > struct FactoryModel : FactoryConcept {
        FactoryModel( const _Ty& t ) : factory( t ) {}
        virtual ~FactoryModel() {}
    private:
        _Ty factory;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<FactoryConcept> factory;

public:
    template< typename _Ty > FactoryContainer( const _Ty& _factory ) :
        factory( new FactoryModel<_Ty>( _factory ) ) {}
};
```

I'd like to include some kind of method then in the container to compare type, something along the lines of

```
template<typename _Ty> bool isType(){...}
```

but I have *no* idea how to implement that, or if I'm even on the right track there with determining type after using type erasure.

EDIT:
After multiple comments about this being an XY problem, I've decided to reemphasize what I'm doing (which I did state).

I want to have an stl container of type Factory (including any and all instantiated template types) and be able to pluck one out BY the template type.  To me, the best way *I* see to do this (which may not be *the best way*) is to use a type encapsulating container class, and have it able to respond if the contained type is infact using the provided template type.  If it is not, then give up.  I can't use dynamic_cast as suggested as at the time I'm trying to figure it out, I don't have a pointer to either type.  I'm looking into typeid now, and hope it'll solve my problems, but I am still waiting for another possible answer.

EDIT 2:
After playing with several answers, I've found nothing that quite meets my requirements.  Here's the requirements in a nutshell:

base class template:

```
template<typename FactoryType>
class Factory
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<FactoryType> Create() = 0;
    virtual ~Factory(){}
};
```

factory manager class:

```
class Manager
{
    static std::shared_ptr<Manager> singleton;
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Manager> getInstance()
    {
        if (!singleton) singleton = shared_ptr<Manager>(new Manager);
        return singleton;
    }
    template<typename FactoryType>
    Factory<FactoryType>& getFactory()
    {
        //Pick a factory here by the type and return it by reference
        //life cycle is handled by the manager
    }
};
```

Manager will be known about by both the core executable and by various dlls.  The possible types for the factories will not be known at the time that Manager is compiled, and it is referenced by code that has no knowledge of each other.  It is possible, and likely, to have factories loaded in here that I don't and won't know about, as many of those are being made by someone else and put in a dll.

Comment: Please don't use leading underscores (`_`) in C++ as they muddy the code and are reserved by the language in many cases.

Comment: Stylistic remark: return `unique_ptr` if you can, not `shared_ptr`. The former can be bound to the latter at the call site.

Comment: C++, unlike the .NET languages, has incredibly poor reflection support. What is your actual use case?

Comment: Type-*erasure* is more about forgetting the type than (re)discovering what it once was to be honest. Perhaps this is an instance of the XY problem?

Comment: @Luc This looks like a textbook example of the XY problem.

Comment: @MarkB I actually forgot about that.  I got in the habit when I was using underscores to get around macros and such defined in the windows header.

Comment: @AlexandreC. can't use unique_ptr as in some cases the factories are singleton factories, using shared_ptr allows them to hold onto the original.

Comment: @lassombra: hence the "if you can" part of my comment. If you must use `shared_from_this` or similar, you have to return `shared_ptr`, indeed.

Comment: Your very first presumption is wrong: You don't have a "factory class", but rather a factory "class template". Templates are not classes, and in particular they are not *types*.

Comment: @KerrekSB fine, I have a factory base class _template_.  You still totally miss the point.  I need to maintain some kind of collection of various factory<t> with unknown types of t which are not the same for the entire collection, and then get access to the collection based not on some arbitrary dictionary key, but on the type of t.  It's that simple.  Pointing out that I forgot one word at the top does **not** change my goal.  I have multiple times on this site been treated like an idiot while transitioning from c# to c++ and your comment which only points out *one* missed word does not help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you're using C++11, you can store [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) objects.

You retrieve them with the `typeid` operator: `typeid` returns a `const std::type_info&`, but `type_info` is not suitable to be used eg. as keys of maps. So you construct a `std::type_index` object for that purpose. The actual solution is up to you.

Something like

```
std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<factory>>
```

would do for instance (replace `shared_ptr` with the correct pointer type for your design).

Note that in C++ you try hard to avoid run time type information. If you expose what you are trying to achieve, we could try to find a better solution.

---

## EDIT

Provided comparing `std::type_info` objects for equality works across DLL boundaries (since this is a requirement, cf. your comment), you can implement it like this:

```
class FactoryContainer
{
    struct FactoryConcept {
        virtual ~FactoryConcept() {}
        virtual const std::type_info& Type() const;
    };

    template< typename _Ty > struct FactoryModel : FactoryConcept {
        FactoryModel( const _Ty& t ) : factory( t ) {}
        virtual ~FactoryModel() {}
    private:
        _Ty factory;
        const std::type_info& Type() const { return typeid(_Ty); }
    };
    std::shared_ptr<FactoryConcept> factory;

public:
    template< typename _Ty > FactoryContainer( const _Ty& _factory ) :
        factory( new FactoryModel<_Ty>( _factory ) ) {}

    template <typename T>
    bool hasType() const { return factory->Type() == typeid(T); }
};
```

Usage:

```
bool result = container.hasType<double>();
```

Comment: I'm actually not using the full c++11.  I'm using msvc++ 2008, and using a using directive to pull shared_ptr into the std namespace as it got really old really fast typing out std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> all over my code.  One strange thing for me is I prefer to use fully qualified type names more often than not.

Comment: @lassombra: There is no `type_index` in `std::tr1`, and it seems to me that it has not been implemented in msvc10. You can consider designing your own wrapper around `std::type_info`, using the `before` member as a predicate (or comparing `const std::type_info *`s, but this will not work across DLL boundaries).

Comment: That's a tough call as I do plan on having this split across DLL boundaries.  I'm really not sure how to move forward on this.  I had considered preprocessor macros, but the list of available factories and what can be constructed from them is dynamic, and I can't even guarantee at any point that I'll have the entire list, as other people are going to be writing dlls which may add their own factories to this (It's being used partially in conjunction with a plugin system)

Comment: @lassombra: You basically have to write your own RTTI mechanism then. I don't think comparing `std::type_info` objects across DLL boundaries is guaranteed to work by the standard (please ask a separate question for this should you want to know). Believe me, C++ is *really* the wrong language when it comes to reflection. You may also consider trying another approach to your problem -- with a little more background regarding what you plan to use this for we can even help you for this.

Comment: I'll work with this and see if it works out.  I'll try and modify the question a bit to show more of the situation.  I think I've captured thoroughly the requirements, but perhaps if I give more background someone will come up with a completely sideways approach to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've modified the question itself.  I'm still not 100% sure about the comparison across dll boundaries (might not work, but I'm still researching that).

Answer (score -1):

That already exists. It is called `dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)` and it returns true if `ptr` points to `T` or any class derived from `T` assuming that the *static* type of `*ptr` and `T` both have at least one virtual function.

You can also use `typeid()` and related friends to discover information about types at run-time.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` doesn't really return _true_ ... ;)

Comment: ^ in fact it never does :D; it just can be implicitly cast to a boolean.